# How to compare strings using joker characters (* and ?) in Pascal?

Tags: string, wildcard, pascal

What i want is when I type in a string, it searches for that in an other string (A+ English I know).

Something like `a:='*'+b+'*'` has worked once, but I don't remember how I did it.

the code right now is this:

```
b:='x';
readln(a);

if a=('*'+b+'*') then writeln('ok');
else writeln('not ok');
```

And it runs just fine, except it always says "not ok", and that wasn't quite what I wanted to make.

Comment: Some terms which may help you find resources on this: what you've called "joker" characters are usually referred to as "wildcard characters" or just "wildcards"; matching in such a way is known as "pattern matching" or perhaps "fuzzy matching"; some specific ways of doing it are "regular expressions" (or "regex" for short), and "glob"/"globbing" (usually when working with files, but sometimes used as a general term).

Comment: @IMSoP thank you, the googling wildcards solved it

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you've found a solution, you are encouraged to post an answer to your own question so that anyone who comes upon this question will find out what you found out.

Answer (score 1):

I found and IsWild function here and it works fine:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/iswild.html